# Select record using GUID

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I would like to select a record from my table based on a GUID using the following approach:

`dim rows() as MyDataSet.MyTableRow = dataset.MyTable.Select("id = " & Guid.NewGuid.ToString)`

but I get the following exception:

`System.Data.EvaluateException was unhandled`
`Message="Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Guid and System.Int32.`

What is the best way to select a record based on a GUID using vbasic.net from MS Sql Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use GUID's in single quotes - sample in C#:

```
string filter = string.Format("id = '{0}'", Guid.NewGuid.ToString());
DataRow[] rows = dataset.MyTable.Select(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add parens around the single quotes like so...

```
"id = ('" & Guid.NewGuid.ToString & "')"
```